# Stream binary stream with javascript

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, mime-types

I'm exploring different ways of sending files using HTML5, JavaScript, WebSockets, MQTT and HTTP. I've been trying to read a zip file that is located on my server from my local file system and receive that as a binary blob. Once I have that binary blob I wish to forward it to  some other client, but that's another problem.

I'm having some issues with security restrictions when trying to download the file though and I'm not sure that what I'm trying to do is actually possible. Using anything else but "jsonp" as the type renders errors like this:

```
Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I've got some jQuery code here which I was hoping would read the zip file and return a blob to me. I guess it was naive to think that JSONP could deliver binary data instad of just padded json.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'http://example.com/myzip.zip',
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        jsonp : 'callback',
        jsonpCallback : 'jsonpCallback',
        success : function() {
            alert("success");
        }
    });

});

function jsonpCallback(data) {
    alert(data.message);
}
```

This is the error I'm getting which I assume is because I try to get zip data and not json data.

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/zip: "http://example.com/myzip.zip?callback=jsonpCallback&_=1365093133651".
```

Anyway, if anyone have a clue as if it is possible to read a zip file from a 3rd party server and save it as a binary blob in a javascript variable, I would be very happy.

Comment: jsonp just creates a `<script>` tag to my knowledge, it doesn't actually do a true cross-domain request.

Comment: JSONP expects JSON data, not a binary stream. The other server is not going to give you a JASON MIME type, so this won't work.

Comment: @BradM Thank you for your quick responses. So I guess there is noway to read the zip-file from a server using javascript on a local client?

Comment: @Diodeus I'd gladly accept that as an answer if you post is as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONP expects JSON data, not a binary stream. The other server is not going to give you a JSON MIME type - it will be a ZIP file, so this won't work.

Comment: You wrote this a year ago and I have the same problem where I need to transfer binary data with JSONP, has anything changed in the past year?